# How to fix Google_Service_Exception: Client is unauthorized error in PHP-5.6.40 (Service account)

Tags: google-api-php-client, php-5.6

I want to install a file upload system on Google Drive to avoid creating a load on my server. I did it first (with [google-api-php-client/examples/simple-file-upload.php](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-file-upload.php)). But I learned that I have to refresh the token every hour. So I started searching on "How do I do it permanently?" I found service account option. I've been searching for days. But I couldn't get it to work correctly. Here are my codes;

HTML

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploaded.php">
    <input type='file' name="File" required />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

uploaded.php

```php
<?php
ini_set ('display_errors', 'on');
ini_set ('log_errors', 'on');
ini_set ('display_startup_errors', 'on');
ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);

require 'upload/vendor/autoload.php';
require 'upload/templates/base.php';

$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setAuthConfig('upload/service-account-credentials.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setSubject("davidturkiye@gmail.com");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$getFile_Name = $_FILES["File"]["name"];
$getFile_File = $_FILES["File"]["tmp_name"];

$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array('name' => $getFile_Name ));
$result = $service->files->create(
    $file,
    array(
        'data' => file_get_contents($getFile_File),
        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
        'fields' => 'id'
    )
);
$Drive_id = $result->id;
echo '
<p>Your call was successful! Check your drive for the following files:</p><br />
<li><a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id='.$Drive_id.'" target="_blank">'.$getFile_Name.'</a></li><br />
<li><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='.$Drive_id.'" target="_blank"></a>'.$getFile_Name.'</a></li>
';
?>
```

I get this error when I run it;

```html
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested." }' in /home/veromsag/davidturkiye.com/panel/upload/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0 /home/veromsag/davidturkiye.com/panel/upload/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 /home/veromsag/davidturkiye.com/panel/upload/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(176): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 /home/veromsag/davidturkiye.com/panel/upload/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run() #4 /home/veromsag/davidturkiye.com/panel/upload/src/Google/Client.php(831): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client in /home/veromsag/davidturkiye.com/panel/upload/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118
```

I tried [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/801#issuecomment-171417538) but doesn't work. I get a similar error.